# julia not finding "standard" packages (or LOAD_PATH)?

Tags: julia, startup, load-path

Upgraded [from 1.5.3] to Julia 1.6.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 [Windwos 10 WSL2] info: building from julia github repo and not via `apt`
My local clone resides on the Windows filesystem and I navigated there with bash shell to start the build process from within that Ubuntu bash shell.
After that starting `julia` in `~` (or any other place) had it throwing errors because of packages not being on the path.
So I fully removed the `~/.julia/config/startup.jl` script since I have a lot of `using this and that` going on there to have a look at it and
what I get is the following within julia prompt when [starting it and] importing `Pkg`

```
julia> import Pkg
ERROR: ArgumentError: Package Pkg not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Pkg")` to install the Pkg package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:893
julia>
```

Checking `LOAD_PATH` all looks sane to me

```
shell> echo $LOAD_PATH
@ @v#.# @stdlib

shell>
```

Final piece of information

```
> whereis julia 
julia: /etc/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
> which julia
/usr/local/bin/julia
```

```
julia> Base.load_path()
2-element Vector{String}:
 "/home/gwd/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml"
 "/usr/local/bin/julia-1.6.3/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6"
```

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.6.3
Commit ae8452a9e0 (2021-09-23 17:34 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-11.0.1 (ORCJIT, icelake-client)
```

Any ideas - what is wrong here?
I did find out that

```
cat .julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml
```

produces

```
[deps]
AlphaVantage = "6348297c-a006-11e8-3a05-9bbf8830fd7b"
Arrow = "69666777-d1a9-59fb-9406-91d4454c9d45"
BenchmarkTools = "6e4b80f9-dd63-53aa-95a3-0cdb28fa8baf"
CSV = "336ed68f-0bac-5ca0-87d4-7b16caf5d00b"
CoinbasePro = "3632ec16-99db-4259-aa88-30b9105699f8"
Conda = "8f4d0f93-b110-5947-807f-2305c1781a2d"
DataFrames = "a93c6f00-e57d-5684-b7b6-d8193f3e46c0"
DataFramesMeta = "1313f7d8-7da2-5740-9ea0-a2ca25f37964"
DataStructures = "864edb3b-99cc-5e75-8d2d-829cb0a9cfe8"
DocumenterTools = "35a29f4d-8980-5a13-9543-d66fff28ecb8"
Flux = "587475ba-b771-5e3f-ad9e-33799f191a9c"
Formatting = "59287772-0a20-5a39-b81b-1366585eb4c0"
FreqTables = "da1fdf0e-e0ff-5433-a45f-9bb5ff651cb1"
GLM = "38e38edf-8417-5370-95a0-9cbb8c7f171a"
HTTP = "cd3eb016-35fb-5094-929b-558a96fad6f3"
IJulia = "7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a"
JuMP = "4076af6c-e467-56ae-b986-b466b2749572"
LanguageServer = "2b0e0bc5-e4fd-59b4-8912-456d1b03d8d7"
OhMyREPL = "5fb14364-9ced-5910-84b2-373655c76a03"
Pipe = "b98c9c47-44ae-5843-9183-064241ee97a0"
PlotThemes = "ccf2f8ad-2431-5c83-bf29-c5338b663b6a"
Plots = "91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80"
Pluto = "c3e4b0f8-55cb-11ea-2926-15256bba5781"
PyCall = "438e738f-606a-5dbb-bf0a-cddfbfd45ab0"
PyPlot = "d330b81b-6aea-500a-939a-2ce795aea3ee"
RCall = "6f49c342-dc21-5d91-9882-a32aef131414"
RDatasets = "ce6b1742-4840-55fa-b093-852dadbb1d8b"
Revise = "295af30f-e4ad-537b-8983-00126c2a3abe"
StaticLint = "b3cc710f-9c33-5bdb-a03d-a94903873e97"
StatsBase = "2913bbd2-ae8a-5f71-8c99-4fb6c76f3a91"
StatsPlots = "f3b207a7-027a-5e70-b257-86293d7955fd"
SymbolServer = "cf896787-08d5-524d-9de7-132aaa0cb996"
Unitful = "1986cc42-f94f-5a68-af5c-568840ba703d"
```

as well as this in the `.julia/environments/v1.6//Manifes.toml`

```
...
[[Pkg]]
deps = ["Artifacts", "Dates", "Downloads", "LibGit2", "Libdl", "Logging", "Markdown", "Printf", "REPL", "Random", "SHA", "Serialization", "TOML", "Tar", "UUIDs", "p7zip_jll"]
uuid = "44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f"
...
```

so how come `Pkg` is suddenly not in `Project.toml` - or am I supposed to look elsewhere for it - and how am I supposed to add it if `Pkg` is not available? :-(

Could the installation be faulty?

Comment: Can you run `Base.load_path()` and check the actual directories it shows, whether they exist, and whether the last one (`stdlib`) contains a `Pkg` directory under it?

Comment: running `versioninfo()` can also help finding out what is going on with environment variables

Comment: will update above info ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok what I learned (so far) is that mixing WSL2 filesystem with the underlying Windows filesystem will break respectively result in a "faulty" build which then produces 'interesting' behavior/errors.
So one should not get too eager or experimental with testing all imaginable combos of places (meaning paths and folders) julia can reside at or be build in :-)